# Neo4jClient c# Where Has set dynamically

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

I have this query:

```
var query = client.Cypher
               .Match("(store:Store)")
               .Where("has(store.en_GB)")
               .Return<Store>("store");

        return query.Results.ToList();
```

What I want is for 'en_GB' to be able to be set from a variable called locale, but I have no idea how this would be possible.

I thought it may be as simple as

```
.Where("has(store.{param})")
.WithParam("param",region)
```

but that didn't work, so is it possible. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var locale = "en_GB";

var query = client.Cypher
               .Match("(store:Store)")
               .Where(String.Format("has(store.{0})", locale))
               .Return<Store>("store");

        return query.Results.ToList();
```